# What are some good public places where a writer can sit and write?

Tags: resources, process, conventions

I often see people give advice about the creative/grammatical aspect of writing, but I see very little advice about the physical mechanics of actually being a writer. For instance, I know that there is always nuance in an individual writer's process, but at the end of the day, all writers sit around for a few minutes and type up words.

In particular, I think that there is very little discussion about what sort of places/environments a writer should consider to maximize the efficiency/quality of their writing. For instance, I sometimes find it very hard to write at home due to the fact that I share my home with many other people.

What are some good public places that a writer should consider when they wish to maximize their output/quality of their writing?

Answer (score 6):

What place you will be most productive in will depend on many individual factors. Not all authors work best under the same circumstances.

- Some writers prefer to write in their home, others prefer to write away from home.
- Some prefer quiet places, others prefer lively places.
- Some write best in a work atmosphere, with others working around them, others like to listen to music or have the tv running in the background.

And so on.

The best approach is to try different places and different circumstances and find out what works best for you. Here are some ideas about what you might try:

- living room or other common room in your home
- [in the bathtub](https://www.josephpatrickpascale.com/post/writing-process-dalton-trumbo-writing-in-the-bathtub-the-duality-of-screenwriter-novelist)
- on a makeshift desk between washing machine and dryer in the laundry room (like Stephen King)
- home office
- office, coworking space
- public or university library
- café, book store, museum, botanical garden, zoo
- public transport (if you have a season ticket)
- train stations, bus stations, malls
- public park, playground
- indoor or outdoor swimming pool
- summer house, garden shed, mountain shelter
- hotel room
- your car or camper van
- a friend's place
- writer's retreat
- any place else where you can sit

You can also experiment with "writing" while you walk, for example by using a dictaphone or typing into your mobile phone or writing into a notebook.

Comment: Agatha Christie: [“I can write anywhere, thank goodness. Plots have never been a difficulty for me.”](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2017/07/31/plots/) So she might not be the best example. (Also, I can't find evidence she actually did the _writing_ in the tub!)

Comment: In the bathtub https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Death_of_Marat_by_David.jpg

Comment: @RUOK_ I'm just not so sure that is the desired creative result...